# PHP - Multi line random array

Tags: php, arrays, random

Say we have an array like this with 1 being two values and 2 being two values and 3, etc

```
$language = array 
(
    "1"=>array
    (
      "Hola",
      "Spanish"
    ),
    "2"=>array
    (
      "Fáilte",
      "Irish"
    ),
    "3"=>array
    (
      "Yasou",
      "Greek"
    )
);
```

How would I randomly select ONLY 1 of 3 arrays and display the two values it has.

So something like this, $language[2][1], thats in $language[2][2].
Which should be,  Fáilte, thats in Greek

Answer (score 4):

PHP has it's own random array function: array_rand(). Use it like so:

```
$random_key = array_rand($language);
echo $language[$random_key][0];
echo $language[$random_key][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a random set of words using the following code and then echo the two results like so:

```
$row = rand(0,sizeof($language)-1);
echo $language[$row][0];
echo $language[$row][1];
```

This is assuming that your array actually starts from 0 as most arrays do. If it really starts from 1, you can use the code posted in the answer below instead.

Comment: This code is wrong. It would choose a random first entry and a random second entry, not the first and second entry from the same array.

Comment: Furthermore, it will never select the last entry, and crash if it tries to select the zeroth.